# Data label is getting shown inside of the bar in sometimes

Tags: highcharts

Sometimes the data label is getting shown inside of the bar. 
For example in the given jsfiddle for the bar for 'Asia' the data label is showing inside the bar itself.
Is there any way to display the data labels always outside of the bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/n3me6r8k/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 2012',
        data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
    }]
});
```

Comment: It is shown inside because there is not enough space to keep it outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could be done by setting two params more in your dataLabels configuration, namely:

```
dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        crop: false,
        overflow: "none"
}
```

Normally, Highcharts will move label inside the bar when it could be cropped by frame of div. Configuration above, allows you to set that labels will not be cropped, even they are out of chart container.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/8m1b4arv/

API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E.dataLabels.crop